# Use of a USB Wifi dongle in both AP and client modes

Tags: wifi, usb, buster

I have a Rpi 4B running Buster and a AWUS036ACM USB Wifi dongle connected to it. I am looking at configuring it as an access point and a client.

When I type:

`iw list | grep "valid interface combination" -A 8`,

I get:

```
 #{ IBSS } <= 1, #{ managed, AP, mesh point, P2P-client, P2P-GO } <= 2, total <= 2, #channels <= 1, STA/AP BI must match
```

Interpreting this result after reading about it, I thought I could have the managed and AP features at the same time although not sure. I am looking for advice on this topic! Thinking it could be a valid configuration, I tried to implemeent this configuration following the information in [Access point as WiFi router/repeater, optional with bridge](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/89803/access-point-as-wifi-router-repeater-optional-with-bridge). With or without systemd-networkd, I can't set it up as I would like. I can either have the AP or the client but not both. Any suggestion, if it is not a limitation of the USB key is welcome!

Added on Feb. 04, 2024

I investigated a bit further the issue described in the original post. I could check that if I remove the USB dongle wifi, the combination AP with station is working using the Rpi4 wifi hardware. On the other hand, if I disable the Rpi4 wifi setting `dtoverlay=disable-wifi` in `/boot/config.txt`, I have the issue back where the usb wifi dongle does not work with both AP and station configuration.
The command `journalctl -xe` indicates that the uap0 interface could not be set up with the explanation: `Name not unique on network`.

It does seem to be due to the specific wifi dongle I use. I tried to meet the requirement of the USB wifi dongle setting `beacon_int` to 1 in the `hostapd.conf` file to the same value that is used by my router but it does not change anything.

Any ideas are welcome as I am running out of ideas for the moment!

Best regards,

JF